# Whats wrong with this guess the number game code?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, random, while-loop

```
#Guess my number

import random

print ("Welcome to the guess my number game")
print ("***********************************")
print ("You will choose a random number between 1-100")
print ("and the computer must guess what it is.")
print ()

number = int(input("Please choose a number between 1-100: "))
guesses = 0
guess = 0

while guess != number:
    guess = ("My guess is: ",random.randint(1,100))
    guesses=guesses+1

    if guess > number:
        print("Lower...")
        continue

    elif guess < number:
        print ("Higher...")

    else:
        print ("Well done you have guessed my number and it took you")          print ("guesses,"guesses!")
```

Basically you choose a number and the computer has to keep guessing until it gets it right but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: What is wrong? What errors are you getting??

Comment: There are at least two errors in the code; `guess` is a tuple but you try to compare it with an integer, you never ask for a new guess in the loop. Which one did you have the most problems with?

Comment: I am not exactly sure but the computer says it has something to do with this line:

Comment: guess = ("My guess is: ",random.randint(1,100))

Comment: Also in the last print statement `print ("guesses,"guesses!")` there is an error. I think it goes into infinite loop because `while guess != number: ` is always true and depending on number generated and gets stuck in either one of the condition.

Comment: Ok thanks but I'm still having a problem with the main part of the code because the error says-                                                                   `if guess > number:
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() > int()`

Answer (score 0):

You should learn basic debugging skills.  The simplest way to debug this program would be to add `print()` statements to see what values are in your variables.

Your basic problem is that you set `guess` to a tuple with two values: the string `"My guess is: "` and a random number from 1 to 100.  You probably intended to set `guess` to just the number.

You probably want something like this:

```
guess = random.randint(1,100)
print("My guess is: {}".format(guess))
```

This will get you one step closer.  Then you will need to figure out how to change the program so that it narrows down the guess range.  If you have trouble with that, maybe you should find someone to tutor you a bit.

Comment: The computer is supposed to keep guessing random number between 1-100 until it gets the right one. So guess must keep changing until it gets it right.

Comment: You are not setting `guess` to the number.  You are setting it to a `tuple` containing two values: a string, and the number.  This isn't right.

Comment: I went ahead and spelled it out for you.  I encourage you to get some tutoring, or work your way through an online Python tutorial such as: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/